# Configure WTP plugin to handle non-standard project structure

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I have a web app project that looks like this:

```
Project/
  src/main/java/...
  src/main/resources/...
  target/MyProject-0.01-SNAPSHOT/
    META_INF/...
    WEB-INF/...
    App.html
    App.css
    etc..
```

I want to start Tomcat from within Eclipse.
  In the past when I've done web-apps the stuff that Tomcat is interested in is available in a `war/` directory in the root of my project.
 The WTP plugin seems to know to copy the contents of that into a hidden tomcat directory (`wtpwebapps`) in my workspace, then it starts Tomcat.
  Now, however, it doesn't seem to be copying anything, which I suspect is because it doesn't know that it's actually in `target/MyProject-0.01-SNAPSHOT/`.

How do I tell Eclipse/WTP where the root of my application is?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found it - This is controlled by the Project->Properties->Deployment Assembly pages.